# How can I setup the Microphone to work on Thinkpad X1 Carbon 6th Generation?

Tags: xubuntu, pulseaudio, microphone

I'm using Xubuntu 18.04 LTS everything works out of the box on the ThinkPad X1 Carbon 6G except the microphone it is just picking up static. I don't know if its an issue with **alsa** or **pulseaudio**. When I freshly install the operating system it works fine and I can hear my voice then after a couple of boots the microphone starts hearing just static.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/q2GxN.png

```
**** List of CAPTURE Hardware Devices ****
card 0: PCH [HDA Intel PCH], device 0: ALC285 Analog [ALC285 Analog]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
```

Comment: I have an X1C gen 7, and for me the built-in microphone doesn't work at all, it doesn't seem to be detected.  Very annoying.